# Streaming socket service with EventMachine in Ruby not working

Tags: ruby, sockets, eventmachine

I have the following EventMachine-based Ruby client, but nothing outputs when it connects to the server:

```
EventMachine.run do
  conn = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://localhost:10000')
  http = conn.get

  http.stream do |data|
    puts data  # THIS SHOULD BE OUTPUTTING SOMETHING
  end

  trap("INT")  { puts 'INT'; http.close; EventMachine.stop }
  trap("TERM") { puts 'TERM'; http.close; EventMachine.stop }
end
```

And the service:

```
module Simulation
  class QuoteService < EM::Connection
    def post_init
      puts "CONNECTION ESTABLISHED"  # THIS DOES OUTPUT

      EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(1) do
        puts "test data"  # THIS DOES OUTPUT
        send_data("test data")
      end
    end
  end
end

EventMachine.run do
  Signal.trap("INT")  { EventMachine.stop }
  Signal.trap("TERM") { EventMachine.stop }

  EventMachine.start_server('0.0.0.0', 10000, Simulation::QuoteService)
end
```

I think something is incorrect with the service. Any ideas why the client outputs nothing?

Comment: hey Chad ..i am facing similar problem with my streaming twitter api ..did you find solution ?

Comment: Hi @RahulDess, unfortunately I don't remember. I did get a WebSocket service running, however, and you can see it [here](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_websocket_service/blob/master/config.ru) and [here](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/trading_websocket_service/blob/master/lib/web_socket_service.rb).

Answer (score 2):

Both your server and client work fine. Try and connect with the client to `google.com:80` for example and you will see it works.

For the server just do `telnet localhost 10000` and you will see here too that the server starts printing out `test data`.

But the problem is your server is not compatible with your client. Your client expects a HTTP server, but the server you're running is a simple `EM::Connection` that does not serve HTTP clients.

So when the client connects it expects a standard HTTP response, but all it gets is `test data`. So the `stream` part of the code will never get called.

You need to either run a HTTP server, or change the client to use `EM::Connection` instead of `HttpRequest`. I.e. both client and server need to talk the same protocol.